# Adding multiple sub items to a ListViewItem using AddRange fails

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

When using

```
lvi.SubItems.AddRange(new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem[5]);
Debug.Assert(lvi.SubItems.Count == 5);
```

the assert fails, lvi.SubItems.Count is 1, and accessing `lvi.SubItems[1]` fails.

What? Shouldn't that add 5 items?

(To clarify: I know I can add them individually using Add() - I'm asking why this doesn't work)

---

Larger context: listView1 is a winforms listview in Details view with 6 columns added:

```
   public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
        listView1.Items.Add(lvi);

        int expectedCount = 6;
        Debug.Assert(listView1.Columns.Count == expectedCount);
        if (lvi.SubItems.Count != expectedCount - 1)
        {
            lvi.SubItems.Clear();
            lvi.SubItems.AddRange(new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem[expectedCount - 1]);
            Debug.Assert(lvi.SubItems.Count == expectedCount - 1);
        }

    }
```

(VS Express 2013RC, VS 2008 Pro)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below

```
lvi.BeginUpdate();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   lvi.SubItems.Add(String.Empty); // adding empty items 
lvi.EndUpdate();
Debug.Assert(lvi.SubItems.Count == expectedCount - 1);
```

if you want to use AddRange

```
vi.SubItems.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(string.Empty, expectedCount - 1).ToArray());
```

Comment: Yeah, I have a worekaround, I am wondering why AddRange doesn't work (or whether I'm doing something wrong with it)

Comment: when you add `ListViewSubItem[expectedCount - 1]` all sub items are null, that may be the reason behind this

Comment: d'oh, I was thinking structs, not objects. Thanks!